# OpenLayers map.events.register throws TypeError

Tags: javascript, openlayers-3

I need to see the event of my map in OpenLayers 3 but my JavaScript doesn't work.

This is my code:

```
var map = new ol.Map({
  layers: [raster, vector],
  target: 'map',
  view: new ol.View({
            projection: 'EPSG:900913',
            center: [-110000, 4600000],
            zoom:5
        })
});
 map.events.register("zoomend", this, function (e) {
    if (map.getZoom() === this.mapMaxZoom) {
        // Don't cluster at this level. No matter what.
        this.vector.strategies[0].threshold = 1000;
        console.log("setting the clustering strategy to 1000");
    }
});
```

And the console output:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'register' of undefined
```

Please help me.

Comment: if there are other ways to log the event, please tell me

Comment: Do you want to set a max zoom? See http://openlayers.org/en/v3.9.0/apidoc/ol.View.html constructor options.

Answer (score 0):

Try using map.on() with the 'moveend' event as follows:

```
map.on('moveend', function(e) {...});
```

See the following for a complete example:

http://openlayers.org/en/v3.9.0/examples/moveend.html